# invariance of integrals for homotopy equivalent spaces

Tags: integration, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I just wanted to know whether the integral of a closed n-form is invariant if we integrate it over homotopy equivalent spaces. This seems like a generalization of "Homotopy invariance of line integral on manifolds". Am I right?

Something like:
$$ \int_{\Sigma} \omega = \int_{\Sigma'} \omega$$
for homotopy equivalent $\Sigma\equiv \Sigma'$

Edit: Ok, I found an obvious counterexample by setting $\Sigma=$n-dimensional ball and $\Sigma'=\{0\}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $\omega= dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$.
However, I'm still curious as to the correct generalization of "Homotopy invariance of line integral on manifolds" since it is mentioned in page 2 here  http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9706092v1.pdf

Comment: What you are looking for is maybe stokes theorem. That is for any singular n-chain $\sigma$ and an $n-1$ form $\omega$ one has $\int_{\sigma} d\omega = \int_{\partial \sigma} \omega$. This is simply stokes theorem in its general form. In the article you mentioned the author has just used this theorem.

Comment: I don't see how the n-sphere could be homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: hey Nimda, yes, i made a mistake. I meant the n-dimensional ball.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expression doesn't make sense. If $\omega$ is a form on $\Sigma$, then it's not a form on $\Sigma'$! You need a map $f:\Sigma'\to \Sigma$ to compare them. So a better version of your claim would be $\int_{\Sigma'} f^*\omega=\int_\Sigma\omega$ when $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. This is now false, rather than undefined.

What's missing from your conjecture is *closedness*. For closed forms, it's nearly true as I just stated it, and the reason is Stokes' theorem, as has been mentioned. For suppose $f:\Sigma'\to \Sigma$ is a homotopy equivalence with homotopy inverse $g$, so $F:\Sigma \times I\to \Sigma$ is a homotopy with $F_0=\text{id}_\Sigma$ and $F_1=fg.$ Then $\int_\Sigma \omega-\int_{\Sigma} (fg)^*\omega=\int_{\Sigma\times I} d(F^*\omega)=\int_{\Sigma\times I} F^*(d\omega)=0$, since by hypothesis $d\omega=0$. But also $\int_{\Sigma} (fg)^*\omega=\int_{\Sigma'} f^*\omega,$ as was to be shown.

Remember I said *nearly* true earlier? This is because the integral of $f^*\omega$ is really only defined on $\Sigma'$ if $\omega$ has the same degree as the dimension of $\Sigma'$, so one should also make that restriction. One more observation: this is actually a special case of a more general theorem, which is the most valuable one to remember, and which has the same proof. Namely,

> **Theorem** If $f,g:\Sigma'\to \Sigma$ are homotopic maps and $\Sigma'$ a smooth $k$-manifold and $\omega$ a closed $k$-form on $\Sigma$, then $\int_{\Sigma'}f^*\omega=\int_{\Sigma'}g^*\omega.$

Comment: Thanks! you filled in all the gaps i had! By the way, is this another expression of a property I'm just reading about homology groups being the same for homotopy equivalent spaces?

Comment: Yes, the integral of a closed form is a homological notion, so they're the same fact up to some technical detail.

Comment: Kevin: Would you mind adding what the precise requirements on $f$, $g$ and $F$ are? Clearly, they must be differentiable but is there anything else?

Comment: May I ask why are you claiming that $\int_{\Sigma} (fg)^*\omega=\int_{\Sigma'} f^*\omega,$? This seems very weird. $g$ could be, for instance, the inclusion of a smaller space in a bigger one.

Comment: @balu The requirements are the ones enough to fulfill Stokes theorem, so $C^2$ would be enough.

Comment: Can you explain why $\int_{\Sigma} (fg)^\ast \omega = \int_{\Sigma'} f^\ast \omega$. That seems to be the most important point, but you just skip it.