# Prop 12.8 in Bott & Tu

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

This proposition in Bott & Tu have been haunting me for a year or so since I always have to come back to this book for references. More precisely, the second equality in Proposition 12.8 in page 135 of [Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/botttu.pdf) has a weird assertion.

Let $E \twoheadrightarrow X$ be a vector bundle over a manifold $X$, $S_0$ the image of the zero section, $S$ the image of a section transversal to $S_0$, $Z = S \cap S_0$, $x \in Z$ (by identifying $S_0$ and $X$) and $S_x = (N_{Z/S})_x$.

Let $\Phi$ be the Thom class of $N_{Z/X}$. The authors claim that $$\int_{S_x} \Phi = \int_{E_x} \Phi$$, because $S_x$ and $E_x$ are homotopic modulo the region in $E$ where $\Phi$ is zero.

In this context, this justification makes no sense. The unique possible theorem that they're alluding to is contained in the answer of [invariance of integrals for homotopy equivalent spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942528/invariance-of-integrals-for-homotopy-equivalent-spaces) . However this still makes no sense in the equality above even by fixing a homotopy equivalence $f: S_x \rightarrow E_x$ since $f^* \Phi \neq \Phi$ might happens.

**I would like a clarification of the equality mentioned above.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of fixing a homotopy equivalence from the beginning, and then run the risk of having $f^*\Phi \neq \Phi$, construct a homotopy equivalence respecting $f^*\Phi = \Phi$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Malkoun Thanks for your comment. Could you, please, clarify the construction of this homotopy?

Comment: sorry, I have been very busy. Is there a way to continue this discussion by email or private messages? I basically have to go back to the original text to be able to answer your question properly.

Comment: @Malkoun I remember there's a chat option here, but I don't know how this works. If you are very busy, you don't need to lose your time here, so I won't insist in asking for a clarification unless you're interested in the problem. In any case, if by any change you find out an explicit solution, I would be glad in reading an answer.

Comment: Here is what I suggest. Define an isotopy by making the section "more and more vertical" (referring to Fig. 12.3 in Bott and Tu), so that at $\tau = 0$, you are at $N_{Z/S}$ and at $\tau = 1$, you are at $E$, over some point $z$ in the zero locus of $S$. By taking a local trivialization of $E$ around $z$, and by definition of the Thom class, which is compactly supported in the vertical directions, you get that $f^*\Phi = \Phi$, modulo regions where $\Phi$ vanishes, which do not affect the integral. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Malkoun Not exactly. You just restated the problem or I'm not getting something too trivial. Let me see if I can clarify what's bugging me. Let $H : X \times I \rightarrow E$ denote these isotopy. Say $H (x, t) = \frac{1}{1-t} \ast s$, where $\ast$ denotes multiplication in the fiber and extend it by continuity to $t = 1$ (maybe this is not well-defined, I don't know). Then $f (H (x, 0)) = H (x,1)$. Now why should $f^* \Phi = \Phi$?

Comment: I think it is because, roughly speaking, the Thom class is vertical, in the sense that the inner product of a tangent vector transverse to the vertical directions gives 0. If that doesn't answer your question or what I am writing doesn't really make sense, then I have to refresh my memory a bit on these things.

Comment: @Malkoun It does make sense. The problem is that I'm not being able to make it precise, which is exactly the point of the question. Defining $f$ locally as the projection onto $E$ would suffice by the verticality of $\Phi$, but this just solve the problem for a trivial bundle. A naive global version of this is picking a metric and defining the value in $E|_{Z}$ which minimizes the distance to a given point in $S$ (that is picking suitable geodesic). However I don't know if this is well-defined and I don't know if I can change coordinates so that this operation is the projection onto $E|_{Z}$.

Comment: I see. I think in Bott and Tu they are considering a single point $z \in Z$, and so around that point, you do not have global bundle issues.

Comment: @Malkoun Of course, I was being silly. An orientation preserving $f$ diffeomorphism for each point in $Z$ is enough. Therefore solving for the trivial bundle is enough. So using the projection onto the fiber $E_x \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and defining $\Phi =\rho dx_{m + 1} \wedge … \wedge dx_{m + n} $ (for a bump function $\rho$) makes $df$ be the projection onto the vertical and by the verticality of $\Phi$, $f^* \Phi = \Phi$ .Thanks for the clarifications. If you want to post the comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Not doing it for the points, I just wanted to help out!

Comment: @Malkoun Alright, thank you. Do you mind if I post a complete answer?

Comment: Of course go ahead. It might help out others.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z \in Z$. It's enough to prove the statement for a trivial bundle since the argument is done pointwise. In this case, $E = \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$, $X = \mathbb{R}^m$, $$(x,s(x)): X \rightarrow E$$, $Z = \mathbb{R}^{m - n} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $$\Phi = \rho (x_1, …, x_{m + n}) dx_1 \wedge … dx_{m + n}$$, where $$\rho : E = \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is a bump function along the fibers of $E$, i.e., $\forall y \forall z (\rho (x, y) = \rho (x', y))$ and $\rho (x, -) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bump function.

By the differentiability of $s$, there's a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $$C = S \cap \prod_{i = 1}^{i = m} (z_i -\varepsilon, z_i + \varepsilon) \times \prod_{i = m + 1}^{m + n} (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$$ is diffeomorphic $Z \times \mathbb{R}^n$ by restricting the projection $f: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^n$ to $C$.

Let $$supp (\rho) \subset \mathbb{R}^m \times \prod_{i = m + 1}^{m + n} (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$$. Then $$df_s (v_1, v_2) =(0, v_2)$$, where the tangent space at each point is being embedded in $E$ (think about a vector attached to a point in $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$). Hence $$f^{*}\Phi = \Phi$$ holds on $\prod (z_i -\varepsilon, z_i + \varepsilon) \times \prod_{i = m + 1}^{m + n} (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$.

Therefore $$\int_{S_z} \Phi = \int_{S_z} f^{*}\Phi = \int_{E_z} \Phi$$.

Obs: Notice that the existence of a transversal section implies that $m \geq n$. I've kept forgetting this and it confused my intuition sometimes. This is why I'm adding this remark.